# Configure proxy setting in nginx forward proxy before another proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have configured nginx as forward proxy and have multiple web servers behind it. All the web servers are sitting behind another proxy server. Hence, I need to configure nginx to forward a request to respective web server via another proxy.

Say example, web site hosted at 192.168.11.82, 11.83, etc.; nginx hosted at 11.11; another proxy server for nginx at 10.10. I have to configure nginx such a way that it routes all the requests to respective server via another proxy server. This is something like we can configure Proxy settings in browser so that all the requests route through proxy servers.

So, it should be...

Client -> nginx proxy server -> another proxy -> actual web servers

How can I achieve this?

Regards,
Hitesh

Comment: What have you tried and what exact problems occur? Theoretically the default configuration should work

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to make exactly the same thing. Proxy requests to another proxy server. And I got it working fine. But I had bad problem with HTTPS requests, while HTTP works just fine. And the funny thing and I need to support both of them. By the way. I used nginScript to pick up proxy server randomly from a list :) Let me know if you need some help with that.

Comment: Hi @AlexPolymath, Can you point me to the solution for HTTP? I got it working with default configuration using "proxy_pass" but GET request is modified to GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: <domain>. But SQUID (my another proxy) expects GET http://<domain>/ HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: <domain> which fails complete flow. Need your help here.